# SQL Server: how do I export entire database?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need to export database from one server and import it into another server.

1. How do I export the entire database to a file, or two files mdf, ldf (either option is fine)
2. How do I import it into a new server using ssms?

In the instructinos frmo ponies, it says:

> In the To a point in time text box,
>   either retain the default (Most recent
>   possible) or select a specific date
>   and time by clicking the browse
>   button, which opens the Point in Time
>   Restore dialog box. For more
>   information, see How to: Restore to a
>   Point in Time (SQL Server Management
>   Studio).
>
> To specify the source and location of the backup sets to restore, click
>   one of the following options:
>
> ```
> From database
>
> Enter a database name in the list box.
> ```

I am unable to type anything in restore

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241108/i-backed-up-the-database-in-ssms-sql-server-how-do-i-restore-it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using SQL Server Management Studio, you use **Backup/Restore** feature.  [The Restore process is laid out in the MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx)  And [here's the MSDN article for backing up a database...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)

Obviously, you restore to another SQL Server database instance (a "database instance" can contain multiple databases.).  The version of the instance can be newer than the version the backup came from - the compatibility level will just be set accordingly.

Comment: i tried this and i pointed to the file but it gave me access denied

Answer (score 10):

If you want to export / save **all data** of a **database** into a .sql file, do this:

1. **Right click** on the **database** in SQL Server Management Studio
2. **Tasks** -> **Generate Scripts**
3. Script entire database and all database objects
4. Next
5. Click - **Advanced**
6. Scroll down to **Types of data to script** and set from Schema only -> **Schema and data** -> Ok
7. Save as script file (name it and save it where you want it)
8. Next
9. Next

Done ✔️

*You can open the file now and see that all values are also included now*

Answer (score 5):

If you want to generate a .sql file:

- right click on the database in SQL Server Management Studio
- select **Tasks->Generate Scripts...** .
- In the dialog that pops up, **Select All** on the screen that says "Select database objects to script"

The generated .sql file can be opened again in SQL Server Management Studio and be run. If the .sql file is very large, see [How do you import a large MS SQL .sql file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431913/how-do-you-import-a-large-ms-sql-sql-file)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to backup the database. This will backup to one file. Then take that file to your new server and do a restore. This should restore everything, from tables to stored procedures to foreign keys and all the data.

Comment: i tried this and i pointed to the file but it gave me access denied

Comment: Thanks, Does this even backup users for a specific database?

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you just want to move a database to a new server, Detach/Attach is a quicker option.  Backup/Restore is what you want if you want to keep the original database in place.

Comment: i tried this and i pointed to the file but it gave me access denied