# SQL Server: where do I do put database so that it appears in the listbox

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-restore

I am trying to restore a DB

I am getting this prompt, however I am unable to point to a database to restore from

Has anyone else experienced this horrific problem?

[alt text http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/6569/56091244.png](http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/6569/56091244.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you backed up a database to a file, click the **From device** radio button and [follow the instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx).

Comment: i tried this and i pointed to the file but it gave me access denied

Comment: @|__: if you want to restore a file, that file has to be on that server machine - you cannot restore to a remote server if the file is on your local machine. Could that be the problem by any chance??

Answer (score 3):

One thing that might bite you in the backend is the fact that the SQL Server backup will contain the path where it wants to be restored to (the original paths).

If you select your backup file, make sure to select the checkbox in the `Restore` column, and then click on the `Options` page on the left:

[image]

Once you do, you should see the path where SQL Server wants to restore the data and log files to - you might need to adapt that to your own situation on your machine:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not right. You need to read the article OMG Ponies posted earlier: [SQL Server: how do I export entire database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240978/sql-server-how-do-i-export-entire-database). You need to select "From Device", then from file and browse from the backup file you created". You sound like a noob, so be careful when handling this database.

Comment: i tried this and i pointed to the file but it gave me access denied

Comment: Doing what you are trying to do should be a 3 step process:

1. Create your backup file
2. Move the backup file to your new server (to a location that you have file access to)
3. Restore from the backup file

That's it!