# Running Multiple SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of queries(more than 200)(in a notepad file) that i run every week in a sequence one by one. Can someone suggest what can i do to run them with one command.
SSIS packages? Sql procedure?

I am a beginner. I am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Stored procedure or just a .sql script would be fine "start myQueries.sql" ... or exec...i dont remember

Comment: How do you run them now?  Why do you run the one-by-one and not all together?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following: [How do you import a large MS SQL .sql file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431913/how-do-you-run-a-300mb-ms-sql-sql-file)

For example:

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -i C:\<your file here>.sql -o
```

Answer (score 1):

If the queries are the same week in and week out, put them in a stored procedure, and schedule them with a SQL Server Agent job.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.WeeklyQueries
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- 200+ queries go here
END
GO
```

If you're feeling ambitious, separate them by function and turn them into several stored procedures.

Once you have the procedure(s), [create a job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187880%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) with a Transact-SQL step that points to the procedure(s) in the right database(s), and either schedule it to run weekly or just run it on demand every week.