# Import / execute a SQL file in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I try to import / execute this [file](https://github.com/neight-allen/django-kickstarter-scraper#db-dump) to SSMS 2012.

Ι have download and export the zip file and I have a `.sql` file of around 700MB.

I went to `File --> Open --> File` and selected the file but it is not working.

How can I import it?

Comment: How is it not working?   What happens when you do the file > open?

Comment: @TabAlleman Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Comment: Your computer doesn't have enough free memory to load the whole file into an SSMS window.   Close everything you can and try again.

Comment: @TabAlleman I made it but again the same. Thank you for your time and your comments

Answer (score 1):

If the file is too large to open in SSMS then you can execute it using sqlcmd.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572(v=sql.110).aspx

[How do you import a large MS SQL .sql file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431913/how-do-you-import-a-large-ms-sql-sql-file)

Comment: sqlcmd -S <server> -i C:\kickscrape_5-7-13\kickscrape.sql -o I open the cmd command and type the previous but it is not working because it says it could not find the file path in the system

Comment: If it says it can't find the path, then you are not pointing to the correct folder.  Check to make sure C:\kickscrape_5-7-13\ is a valid location in your file system and the account running sqlcmd has access to it.

Comment: I checked it and it is the right path. Should I make something different to the command like <server>?

Comment: maybe sqlcmd isn't in your path environment variable, try changing to the sql install directory before running the command.  `cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\xxx\Tools\Binn' where xxx is your SQL version.  For 2012 it's 110