# sql server2005 back up error : access denied

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to backup my sql server 2005 database using the query

```
backup database marksheet to disk='e:\backup\marksheet.bak'
```

when i execute the query it shows  the following error

> cannot open backup device 'e:\backup\marksheet.bak' operating system
>   error 5(access is denied)

I am using windows xp

please help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot open backup device. Operating System error 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960257/cannot-open-backup-device-operating-system-error-5)

Answer (score 2):

The account running the SQL Server service does not have access to that folder.

It doesn't matter if *you* have access to that folder.

Comment: How to set access to that folder

Comment: @Sheik Syed Mohaideen: Google "NTFS permissions".

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the security permissions on the folder you are trying to backup to. Make sure the service account (Network Service) has write permissions. It may well not do.

SQL on changing the service account changes the permissions on the critical drives it knows about but won't do it for all the drives in a server.

---

Try adding the domain account that runs all SQL Services to the security of "e:\backup\".