# SQL server backup to shared folder

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a backup to a network shared folder with the following code:

```
string filePath = ("\\pc-usuario\folder\backup\backup.bak")
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True", server, database);

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var query = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE [{0}] TO DISK='{1}'", database, filePath);

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandTimeout = 1800;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Got the following error:

> The backup device cannot be opened. Operating system error 5(Access denied.).

If I try it with SQLExpress the same error happens. What am I missing?

Comment: your code needs permission to wirte to the network share, therefore same rules as this thread applies: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7b1045a-efa2-4cf3-bb26-b22c7b2c60d7/how-to-create-a-file-on-a-networkshared-folder?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @Bacon I think SQL server need permission, not my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open backup device. Operating System error 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960257/cannot-open-backup-device-operating-system-error-5)

Answer (score 0):

You havent given the database backup a file name, only a file path

E.g. the final code should read

```
backup database wibble to disk = '\\pc-usuario\folder\backup\wibble.bak'
```

Comment: It has a name, but I missed it when I copied the code.